# bad return type in lambda expression when creating a Long type maxHeap using PriorityQueue

Tags: java, heap, priority-queue, long-integer

I tried to create a Long type maxHeap using PriorityQueue.

```
PriorityQueue<Long> maxHeap = new PriorityQueue<Long>((a, b) -> (b - a));
```

But the compiler returned an error `incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression`

Can someone explain:

1. Why is there an error?
2. What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

1. Why is there an error?

It is an error because the `PriorityQueue<Long>` expects a `Comparator<Long>` and the `Comparator<Long>.compare(Long, Long)` method has the signature `int compare(Long o1, Long o2);`.

Your lambda expression however has a result type `long` and that doesn't match the required signature.

---

2. What's the right way to do it?

Its either using the natural order by using the no-args constructor:

```
PriorityQueue<Long> maxHeap = new PriorityQueue<>();
```

Or providing the correct Comparator by using a method reference to `Long.compareTo(Long)`:

```
PriorityQueue<Long> maxHeap = new PriorityQueue<>(Long::compareTo);
```

---

On a side note: even for `Integer`, `(a, b) -> a - b` is **not** a valid `Comparator<Integer>` lambda.

A comparator must return a value greater than zero if `a` is greater than `b`, but for `int a = 2_000_000_000;` and `int b = -2_000_000_000;` the expression `a-b` has a result less than zero (due to integer overflow).

So even for `Integer` you **must** use `Integer::compareTo` (if you have two `Integer` values)or `Integer::compare` (if you have two `int` values).